# Proteomics automation: Tecan GWL examples for plate loading and unloading from a Liconic Carousel

Tags: automation

I'm having a hard time finding good documentation for examples of advanced GWL commands in Tecan systems. My incubators are Liconic's Storex models, but were sold by Tecan with our robots.

I want to take plates out of the incubator multiple times in a pipetting script and coding that with the GUI is frustrating because there will be a LOT and I'd just like to write a script that writes the gwls instead of make a super ugly-big GUI-driven process that'll be hell to rewrite when I need to modify. FYI: I don't use a barcode scanner, but a barcode file. It seems that using labware generator only puts enough plates on the worktable in the preactions and removes them in the postactions for one iteration of what I'd like to do. I want to stay in the script and load and then put away multiple rounds of 6 plates.

I would be interested in other commands and general advice/wisdom from developing in Tecans using GWL. I have had success with developing processes with basic gwl commands so far and really like the extra control over the robot.

also, can someone with more reputation than me make the new tags tecan, liconic, and gwl? UPDATE: thanks for the tags!

Comment: Are you still looking for this?  I might have some I can share.

Answer (score 0):

So far I realize that GWL is more for LiHa arm than MCA96 or MCA384. Though I can probably still use GWL commands to move plates in a MCA96 script like in a LiHa script. For now, I'm going to embrace the GUI (much as it pains me) and see how ugly-big it gets. Good enough for an early iteration. Still open to dialog on the topic though.

Comment: Per SO guidelines, this new data should be incorporated into your original question. Only actual answers belong here.